# Are 'dummy-folds' a good alternative to recursion?

Tags: haskell

Take a look at the code below, especially the first function `randVectors`.
It creates a vector of random vectors. In order to do that, the random generator `g` has to be 'looped' on; the generator used for creating the first vector is returned and passed along to generate the next vector and so forth. The code compiles and works as expected, but is this the idiomatic way of writing Haskell?

As you see, the step function in the fold ignores what's being folded over. It could be implemented with recursion instead, but that does not seem much better at least in my eyes.

```
import           Control.Monad               as M
import           Control.Monad.ST
import qualified Data.Vector                 as V
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic         as VG
import           Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable as VGM
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed         as VU
import           System.Random


randVectors :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Int -> g -> (V.Vector (VU.Vector Int), g)
randVectors nvecs veclen g =
  foldl step (V.empty, g) [0..nvecs]
    where
  step :: (RandomGen g) => (V.Vector (VU.Vector Int), g) -> Int -> (V.Vector (VU.Vector Int), g)
  step (li, g1) _ =
    (V.snoc li subli, g2)
      where
    (subli, g2) = randVector veclen g1

randVector :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> g -> (VU.Vector Int, g)
randVector n =
  shuffle vector $ VU.length vector
    where
  vector = VU.enumFromN 0 n

shuffle :: (RandomGen g, VG.Vector v a) => v a -> Int -> g -> (v a, g)
shuffle vec size g =
  runST $ do
    vec_mut <- VG.thaw vec
    let swap_random g1 i = do
          let (j,g2) = randomR (0,i) g1
          VGM.swap vec_mut i j
          return g2
    g' <- M.foldM swap_random g [1..size-1]
    vec' <- VG.unsafeFreeze vec_mut
    let vec_sample = VG.take size vec'
    return (vec_sample, g')
```

Comment: I'm more troubled by the fact that you use `foldl` instead of `foldl'` but chi's answer looks like it gets the job done.

Comment: Can I always stick to the strict version (`foldl'`) unless I'm certain that only a partial result of the fold will be used further?

Comment: Won't `unfoldrN` be just as bad since it's not strict?

Comment: You can tune the strictness of an unfold to a great extent by being careful about how you write the function passed to `unfoldrN`. I'm not sure how `foldl` behaves for vectors. It may be good for building a structure lazily, but that's not what you're doing here. If you're using an accumulator that doesn't have lazy structure, you should generally use `foldl'` or `foldr'`. Note however that for *lists*, `foldr'` is no good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't beat them, join them.
And if you can't fold them, unfold them.

Indeed, one could use [`unfoldrN`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.11.0.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:unfoldrN) here:

```
randVectors :: (RandomGen g) => Int -> Int -> g -> (V.Vector (VU.Vector Int), g)
randVectors nvecs veclen = unfoldrN nvecs (Just . randVector veclen)
```

More in detail:

```
unfoldrN :: Int -> (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> Vector a
```

is used as

```
unfoldrN :: Int -> (g -> Maybe (VU.Vector Int, g)) -> g -> Vector (VU.Vector Int)
```

The `Int` is the maximum length of the generated vector, i.e. `nvecs`.
The function `(g -> Maybe (VU.Vector Int, g))` is simply the same thing as `randVector`, except that is can choose to stop the generation early by returning `Nothing` -- we do not need that, so we compose with `Just`. The argument `g` is the initial generator.

Alternatively, one could use a state monad for that `g -> (g, _)` recurring pattern in types, and exploit

```
Data.Vector.replicateM :: Monad m => Int -> m a -> m (Vector a)
```